# uniform convergence of functions over $\mathbb{R}^n$ implies integral convergence of functions with product

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n,f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $g$ goes to infinity at zero but is otherwise continuous, assuming $f_ng$ is integrable, do we have the following convergence?

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_n g \longrightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R^n}} fg $$

Clearly on a compact set not including zero, $g$ is bounded, so $f_ng$ converges uniformly to $fg$ on that set, meaning the integrals converge on that set, but since $g$ blows up to infinity, I don't think $f_ng$ converges to $fg$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I'm having trouble seeing if the integral convergence holds over the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I tried splitting it up into rings of compact sets, but then I ended up with an infinite sum of integrals all converging, but got nowhere with this.

Comment: If $g$ is integrable on some small neighbourhood of $0$, then it follows, otherwise not.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right, split the integral into two via a partition of $\mathbb{R}^n$ about the neighbourhood, use the integrability of $g$ and uniform convergence on the first, on the second $g$ is bounded so the integral converges... right?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I think you will need to assume that $g $ is integrable on all of $\Bbb {R}^n $. Otherwise, something like $g=0$ and $g_k \sim 1/n \cdot 1_{(-k,k)^n \setminus (-1,1)^n}$ (or some variant) can pose problems.

Comment: @PhoemueX Ah, I silently assumed that the supports of the $f_n$ remain inside some fixed compact set, though that's not given in the question. Oops. If the supports spread out, we must indeed demand good behaviour of $g$ at $\infty$ too.